# How to apply a hierarchical or k-means cluster analysis using R?

Tags: r, cluster-analysis

I want to apply a hierarchical cluster analysis with R. I am aware of the `hclust()` function but not how to use this in practice; I'm stuck with supplying the data to the function and processing the output.

I would also like to compare the hierarchical clustering with that produced by `kmeans()`. Again I am not sure how to call this function or use/manipulate the output from it.

My data are similar to:

```
## dummy data
require(MASS)
set.seed(1)
dat <- data.frame(mvrnorm(100, mu = c(2,6,3), 
                          Sigma = matrix(c(10,   2,   4,
                                            2,   3, 0.5,
                                            4, 0.5,   2), ncol = 3)))
```

Comment: I have attempted to improve the original question because (and I am not an independent observer but...) I think the Answers here are at least useful and deserves to remain here. Please help by editing it if you can improve further.

Comment: @Gavin Simpson: You are a saint, and I have reopened the question. I have also deleted all comments previously posted as they're no longer relevant (not to mention a real eyesore), and will clean these up once you see them.

Comment: Does it really make sense to largely replace a busted question that is over a year old and should be answered with the famous "read the manual" or "google for 'hclust R tutorial'"? Plus, I wouldn't be surprised if there are already 10 duplicates here.

Comment: Then close the question as a duplicate. Then the answer can be merged or preserved. If there were no good answers then I would agree, but there is & people were trying to delete this on quality of question alone. At least the question doesn't stink now. Advice on Meta is to do what I have done.

Comment: @BoltClock Thanks for this. I have also edited the Answer so it meshes more with the edited question. The comment trail on the Answer could now do with a clear up if you get a chance. I can delete some of mine but those of the OP will need some mod attention. Will flag later.

Answer (score 63):

For hierarchical cluster analysis take a good look at `?hclust` and run its examples. Alternative functions are in the **cluster** package that comes with R. *k*-means clustering is available in function `kmeans()` and also in the `cluster` package.

A simple hierarchical cluster analysis of the dummy data you show would be done as follows:

```
## dummy data first
require(MASS)
set.seed(1)
dat <- data.frame(mvrnorm(100, mu = c(2,6,3), 
                          Sigma = matrix(c(10,   2,   4,
                                            2,   3, 0.5,
                                            4, 0.5,   2), ncol = 3)))
```

Compute the dissimilarity matrix using Euclidean distances (you can use whatever distance you want)

```
dij <- dist(scale(dat, center = TRUE, scale = TRUE))
```

Then cluster them, say using the [group average hierarchical method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hierarchical_clustering#Linkage_criteria)

```
clust <- hclust(dij, method = "average")
```

Printing the result gives us:

```
R> clust

Call:
hclust(d = dij, method = "average")

Cluster method   : average 
Distance         : euclidean 
Number of objects: 100
Plot the dendrogram
```

but that simple output belies a complex object that needs further functions to extract or use the information contained therein:

```
R> str(clust)
List of 7
 $ merge      : int [1:99, 1:2] -12 -17 -40 -30 -73 -23 1 -52 -91 -45 ...
 $ height     : num [1:99] 0.0451 0.0807 0.12 0.1233 0.1445 ...
 $ order      : int [1:100] 84 14 24 67 46 34 49 36 41 52 ...
 $ labels     : NULL
 $ method     : chr "average"
 $ call       : language hclust(d = dij, method = "average")
 $ dist.method: chr "euclidean"
 - attr(*, "class")= chr "hclust"
```

The dendrogram can be generated using the `plot()` method (`hang` gets the labels at the bottom of the dendrogram, along the x-axis, and `cex` just shrinks all the labels to 70% or normal)

```
plot(clust, hang = -0.01, cex = 0.7)
```

[image: dendrogram]

Say we want a 3-cluster solution, cut the dendrogram to produce 3 groups and return the cluster memberships

```
R> cutree(clust, k = 3)
  [1] 1 2 1 2 2 3 2 2 2 3 2 2 3 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 1 2 3 2 1 1 2 2 2 2 1 1 1 1
 [38] 2 2 2 1 3 2 2 1 1 3 2 1 2 2 1 2 1 2 2 3 1 2 3 2 2 2 3 1 3 1 2 2 2 3 1 2 1
 [75] 1 2 3 3 3 3 1 3 2 1 2 2 2 1 2 2 1 2 2 2 2 2 3 1 1 1
```

That is, `cutree()` returns a vector the same length as the number of observations clustered, the elements of which contain the group ID that each observation belongs. The membership is the ID of the leaf into which each observation falls when the dendrogram is cut at a stated height or, as done here, at the appropriate height to provide the stated number of groups.

Perhaps that gives you enough to be going on with?

For *k*-means, we would do this

```
set.seed(2) ## *k*-means uses a random start
klust <- kmeans(scale(dat, center = TRUE, scale = TRUE), centers = 3)
klust
```

which gives

```
> klust
K-means clustering with 3 clusters of sizes 41, 27, 32

Cluster means:
           X1          X2          X3
1  0.04467551  0.69925741 -0.02678733
2  1.11018549 -0.01169576  1.16870206
3 -0.99395950 -0.88605526 -0.95177110

Clustering vector:
  [1] 3 1 3 2 2 3 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 3 2 3 1 2 1 2 2 1 1 3 2 1 1 3 3 1 2 2 1 3 3 3 3
 [38] 1 2 2 3 1 2 2 3 3 1 2 3 2 1 3 1 3 2 2 1 3 2 1 2 1 1 1 3 1 3 2 1 2 1 3 1 3
 [75] 3 1 1 1 1 1 3 1 2 3 1 1 1 3 1 1 3 2 2 1 2 2 3 3 3 3

Within cluster sum of squares by cluster:
[1] 47.27597 31.52213 42.15803
 (between_SS / total_SS =  59.3 %)

Available components:

[1] "cluster"      "centers"      "totss"        "withinss"     "tot.withinss"
[6] "betweenss"    "size"
```

Here we get some information about the components in the object returned by `kmeans()`. The `$cluster` component will yield the membership vector, comparable to the output we saw earlier from `cutree()`:

```
R> klust$cluster
  [1] 3 1 3 2 2 3 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 3 2 3 1 2 1 2 2 1 1 3 2 1 1 3 3 1 2 2 1 3 3 3 3
 [38] 1 2 2 3 1 2 2 3 3 1 2 3 2 1 3 1 3 2 2 1 3 2 1 2 1 1 1 3 1 3 2 1 2 1 3 1 3
 [75] 3 1 1 1 1 1 3 1 2 3 1 1 1 3 1 1 3 2 2 1 2 2 3 3 3 3
```

In both instances, notice that I also scale (standardise) the data to allow each variable to be compared on a common scale. With data measured in different "units" or on different scales (as here with different means and variances) this is an important data processing step if the results are to be meaningful or not dominated by the variables that have large variances.

Comment: @sridher err, load your data into R. There are a plethora of ways one can do that depending on the format your data are in. I think you need to take a step back and read some of the introductory manuals for R, namely "An Introduction to R" and the "R Data Import/Export" manual, both available here: http://cran.r-project.org/manuals.html

Comment: My dataset is of csv file....i imported it into console using this function    > data1 <- read.csv(file.choose(), header = TRUE) now data1 is my dataset...from this point i'm unable to do....plz can u explain mentioning this data1 variable so that i could get clusters...

Comment: sorry for troubling u...but my head just given the huge dataset and asked me to do it in 2 days :-( ....but i'm completely new to this...plz dont mind for asking silly questions...but for me not silly !

Comment: So in my code, `dat` plays the role of your `data1`. So look at my code, and replace `dat` with `data1` in all the function calls. Now whether this will work or not will depend on what types of data are in your `data1` and as I don't have `data1` I can't say whether the code will work with your data or not.

Comment: @sridher No trouble, I'm just being honest. I've shown you exactly the code you need to run a *k*-means cluster analysis in R. But if you don't know enough R to use it, this website is not the appropriate venue for getting the assistance you need. If I were you, I'd spend a day learning some R, and then day 2 doing the cluster analysis.

Comment: Haha thank u so much mate...i wil do it now and wil check :-)

Comment: mate u have given 3 rows and 3 columns....what about those what ro replace there in c (   ) function??.....n ncol = 3...but for my dataset ncol =20 ! so wat about this modification?

Comment: @sridher - no, you just need the three lines of code immediately after "For k-means, we would do this" in my answer above. Also, as my data are in object `dat` but your data are in `data1`, you need to change the code to use `data1` and not `dat`. The code at the top was just to generate some dummy example data with which to illustrate some of the clustering functions in R.

Comment: so what, is cluster analysis just an easy way to make really really nicely formatted NCAA brackets? Can R fill out my bracket now too?

Comment: @Chase R can do anything - you should know that ;-)

Comment: This is the highest answer/question quality ratio I've seen in a while.

Comment: @Gavin Here's my other +1 :-)

Comment: wow, in relation to question that is THE best answer I've seen here. @Bill, really got more of those? I haven't been around for too long – I haven't see a ratio any better than this.

Comment: Is scale() necessary if all my variables are in the same units but might have different means and variances?

Comment: @HermanToothrot It depends on whether you want the big/abundant things (the things with higher means) to dominate, assuming you're using the Euclidean distance. Other distances are available which may have implicit standardisations so it does depend.