# R produces different result after IO on file

Tags: r

As new to R, I have a question about writing and reading vector data.

My Example 1

```
n = 100
g = 6
set.seed(g)
d <- data.frame(x = unlist(lapply(1:g, function(i) rnorm(n/g, runif(1)*i^2))), 
                y = unlist(lapply(1:g, function(i) rnorm(n/g, runif(1)*i^2))))
plot(d)
require(vegan)
fit <- cascadeKM(scale(d, center = TRUE,  scale = TRUE), 1, 10, iter = 1000)
plot(fit, sortg = TRUE, grpmts.plot = TRUE)
calinski.best <- as.numeric(which.max(fit$results[2,]))
cat("Calinski criterion optimal number of clusters:", calinski.best, "\n")
```

([source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15376075/cluster-analysis-in-r-determine-the-optimal-number-of-clusters)), it prints "Calinski criterion optimal number of clusters: 5" as expected.

Example 2: (write data frame d first, then read it)

```
n = 100
g = 6 
set.seed(g)
d <- data.frame(x = unlist(lapply(1:g, function(i) rnorm(n/g, runif(1)*i^2))), 
                y = unlist(lapply(1:g, function(i) rnorm(n/g, runif(1)*i^2))))

write.table(d, "d.txt", sep='\t', quote=FALSE) #write data frame
d = read.table("d.txt", header=TRUE, sep = '\t') #read later
plot(d)

require(vegan)
fit <- cascadeKM(scale(d, center = TRUE,  scale = TRUE), 1, 10, iter = 1000)
plot(fit, sortg = TRUE, grpmts.plot = TRUE)
calinski.best <- as.numeric(which.max(fit$results[2,]))
cat("Calinski criterion optimal number of clusters:", calinski.best, "\n")
```

However, example 2 prints "Calinski criterion optimal number of clusters: 1".

I think the format (or something else) has been changed after IO from file in R. But i have no knowledge about how R read and write numbers. Can anyone give me some clues, thanks.

EDIT
If the file is written without col name and row name, problem solved.

```
write.table(d, "d.txt", sep='\t', quote=FALSE, row.name=FALSE, col.names=FALSE)
```

When reading, R also reads the row and col names,. 
Another is to escape those names when reading.

Comment: The plot is the same in both cases? The code seem exactly the same...
Did you print after reading again to compare if it is the same (maybe just the `head` of it will do `head(d)`)

Comment: The plot is the same and the print of table frame d is the same.

Comment: Writing numbers to a text file is very likely going to lose some precision. Use `save` or `saveRDS` instead.

Comment: Thanks Joshua, as a beginner and on the experiment data, I'd like to have text file since it is much easier to read and modify. I will use saveRDS in the real data.

Answer (score 0):

The Calinski index cannot be calculated for one group, but it becomes either Inf or -Inf. In the first example it happened to be -Inf, and in the second it happened to be Inf and when you looked for `which.max`, Inf was what you got. I do not know why we actually bother to calculate the index for one-class case, but if you search for the best result, you should ignore the first case. We do so in the `plot` command which gives five clusters as the best result in both cases. The following modification of your code will give the same answer in both cases:

```
calinski.best <- as.numeric(which.max(fit$results[2,-1])) + 1
cat("Calinski criterion optimal number of clusters:", calinski.best, "\n")
```

We had to have `+1` because we omitted one column.

Small details for the Inf/-Inf indeterminacy. As you see in `?cascadeKM`, Calinski criterion is defined as (SSB/(K-1))/(SSW/(n-K)) and for one group K=1 so that SSB/0 = Inf. For one group also SSB=0, but that is computed zero and these are rarely exact in digital computers, and in my computer zero is -2.8e-14 and -2.8e-14/0 = -Inf. In the second example SSB=2.8e-14 and 2.8e-14/0 = Inf. Just ignore the first column when you look for the optimum. Occasionally SSB can be exact zero and then 0/0 = NaN (not a number).