# How to plot clusters with a matrix?

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, data-mining

I have a document dataset, I converted it to a matrix and run the k-means clustering, how do I plot a graph to show the clusters with the matrix?

```
k<-5
kmeansResult<-kmeans(m3,k)
plot(m3, col = kmeansResult$cluster)
points(kmeansResult$centers, col = 1:5, pch = 8, cex = 5)
```

[image]

Comment: see this excellent post on clusters (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15376075/cluster-analysis-in-r-determine-the-optimal-number-of-clusters)

Comment: could you provide a reproducible example? your data or part of it.

Comment: How many dimensions does your screen have? How many does your data set have?

Comment: `dim(m3)`
`[1] 10829   199`

Answer (score 5):

As alluded to in the comments, the problem is that your dataset may have > 2 dimensions (more then 2 variables), whereas your plot is restricted to 2 (or perhaps 3) dimensions. So some sort of dimensionality reduction is needed. The typical way is to run a principal components analysis on the original data and then plot the first two PC's, organized by cluster. So here are three ways to do this in R, using the `mtcars` dataset as an example.

```
df     <- mtcars[,c(1,3,4,5,6,7)]      # subset of mtcars dataset
set.seed(1)                            # for reproducible example
km <- kmeans(df,centers=3)             # k-means, 3 clusters
# using package cluster
library(cluster)
clusplot(df,km$cluster)
```

[image]

```
# using package ade4
library(ade4)
pca    <-prcomp(df, scale.=T, retx=T)  # principal components analysis
plot.df <- cbind(pca$x[,1], pca$x[,2]) # first and second PC
s.class(plot.df, factor(km$cluster))
```

[image]

```
# ggplot solution
pca    <-prcomp(df, scale.=T, retx=T)  # principal components analysis
# gg: data frame of PC1 and PC2 scores with corresponding cluster
gg <- data.frame(cluster=factor(km$cluster), x=scores$PC1, y=scores$PC2)
# calculate cluster centroid locations
centroids <- aggregate(cbind(x,y)~cluster,data=gg,mean)
# merge centroid locations into ggplot dataframe
gg <- merge(gg,centroids,by="cluster",suffixes=c("",".centroid"))
# calculate 95% confidence ellipses
library(ellipse)
conf.rgn  <- do.call(rbind,lapply(1:3,function(i)
  cbind(cluster=i,ellipse(cov(gg[gg$cluster==i,2:3]),centre=as.matrix(centroids[i,2:3])))))
conf.rgn  <- data.frame(conf.rgn)
conf.rgn$cluster <- factor(conf.rgn$cluster)
# plot cluster map
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(gg, aes(x,y, color=cluster))+
  geom_point(size=3) +
  geom_point(data=centroids, size=4) +
  geom_segment(aes(x=x.centroid, y=y.centroid, xend=x, yend=y))+
  geom_path(data=conf.rgn)
```

[image]

Notice that the three options all give differing ellipses! This is because they are defined differently. `clusplot(...)` by default generates "minimum volume ellpises" which have the correct center and orientation, but are sized to just large enough to enclose all the points in the cluster. `s.plot(...)` generates ellipses based on a scale factor that can be set in an argument to the call. The `ggplot(...)` solution generates ellipses which are 95% confidence regions for each cluster (assuming that the points in each cluster follow a bivariate normal distribution). You can see from this that the clusters clearly overlap; this is, several of the points might arguably belong in more than one cluster. This gives a more realistic representation of the data, IMO, which is one of the reasons I prefer it, even though clearly it's more work.

Comment: I tried using your second method and I attached the result in the question. All the 4 clusters seemed to squeeze together, is that possible for me to zoom in?