# Create equally sized clusters based on one attribute of the node

Tags: r, cluster-computing

The title of the question certainly doesn't explain very well what I want to do. Please keep reading to get a better understanding!

I have a cluster of nodes. Each node represents a building and it has some attributes. For example:

```
x coordinate
y coordinate
population
```

What I want is to create clusters of these nodes using a method, which will give me clusters with equal population (based on the attribute).

For example if I want to create 3 clusters (A,B,C) I need the sum of the population of each cluster to be equal to each other like:

```
sum(population)(A) = sum(population)(B) = sum(population)(C)
```

I don't know how to call this exactly. Perhaps something like: Create equally sized clusters based on one attribute..

My question is if I can do this using R statistics or some other tool.

Comment: Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27804926/in-r-is-there-an-algorithm-to-create-approximately-equal-sized-clusters?rq=1) can help

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately its  not what I am looking for. I want to create equal clusters not based on the number of the nodes but based on the number of the population, which is (the population) an attribute of the nodes.