# How to validate clara algorithm while clustering in R?

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, data-mining

I'm using **clara algorithm** for clustering geo-spatial data in R. My data set size is of more than 3 Million observations, with variables Longitude and Latitude. I'm good with R programming.

1. I have used `earth.dist` function from `fossil` package for the metric attribute of the `clara` function from `cluster` package. `metric` says that it supports only `"euclidean"` or `"manahattan"`. But, when I'm using `earth.dist` it not throwing an error or warning. When I checked with sample of random 1000 observations to see the difference `clara` is not giving different results with "euclidean" and `"earth.dist"` distance. Can I use `"earth.dist"` as metric? also please explain me why it is not throwing an error.
2. I have also used **Silhouette Method** to find the number of clusters. I found the number of clusters to be 12 when I set the number of samples to 5 but when I increased the samples to 15, I'm getting the number of clusters to be 6, with input range from 2 to 50

I have followed the [stackoverflow page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15376075/cluster-analysis-in-r-determine-the-optimal-number-of-clusters/15376462#15376462) to find the optimal number of clusters

My questions:

1. How to find the optimal number of samples?
2. How to find the optimal number of clusters?
3. How to find the optimal sample size for clustering using `clara`? I think `samplesize = min(n, 40 + 2k)` i.e. maximum `samplesize = 140` when `k = 50` is very small sample for data set size of more than 3 Million observation.

what are the other methods that can be considered while validating clustering? To keep it simple, how to validate clustering of **clara algorithm**?

Update 1: When I increased `sample = 10` and `sampsize = 400` from default values in R, the number of clusters is converging to 2 when Silhouette Method is used. Why did the number of clusters converge? How does the algorithm work?

Comment: **Use the source, luke**. How does clara interpret the parameter? You say the results are the same qith Euclidean, then it probably used Euclidean and ignored the parameter? Also have a look at OPTICS. There are some nice examples around with clustering millions of coordinates with OPTICS and ELKI.

Comment: Yes, I have checked sources and my doubt was if it is not using `earth.dist` why isn't there any warning or error? Isn't OPTICS computationally expensive? I think I have to calculate the `dist` object from longitudes and latitudes for `optics` which R cannot do for huge data set.

Comment: ELKI uses an index, it does not need a distance matrix then and is much faster, by avoiding pairwise comparisons.

Comment: ELKI is not an option for me now as it will take time learn and understand a java based application

Comment: Hi @midhun-t I'm trying to use CLARA but not sure if I'm doing well. Have you found answer to your questions? I also have a lon, lat, value-day_1,...,value-day_n dataset I want to cluster. Thanks