# R cluster analysis and dendrogram with correlation matrix

Tags: r, statistics, cluster-computing, analysis, dendrogram

I have to perform a cluster analysis on a big amount of data. Since I have a lot of missing values I made a correlation matrix.

```
corloads = cor(df1[,2:185], use = "pairwise.complete.obs")
```

Now I have problems how to go on. I read a lot of articles and examples, but nothing really works for me. How can I find out how many clusters are good for me?

I already tried this:

```
dissimilarity = 1 - corloads
distance = as.dist(dissimilarity) 

plot(hclust(distance), main="Dissimilarity = 1 - Correlation", xlab="")
```

I got a plot, but its very messy and I dont know how to read it and how to go on. It looks like this:

[image]

Any idea how to improve it? And what can I actually get out of it?

I also wanted to create a Screeplot. I read that there will be a curve where you can see how many clusters are correct.

I also performed a cluster analysis and choose 2-20 Clusters, but the results are so long, I have no idea how to handle it and what things are important to look on.

Comment: You can arbitrary determine the number of clusters. It is very controversy how to determine the number of clusters, but some analysis can help you out. Take a look at `kgs` function from `maptree` package.

Comment: I looked it up and read that it should help you to find a good number of clusters. But I am totally new to that subject. What do I have to enter as cluster and diss? Is my corloads = cluster and diss = distance?? kgs (cluster, diss, alpha=1, maxclust=NULL)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To determine the "optimal number of clusters" several methods are available, despite it is a controversy theme.

The `kgs` is helpful to get the optimal number of clusters.

Following your code one would do:

```
clus <- hclust(distance)
op_k <- kgs(clus, distance, maxclus = 20)
plot (names (op_k), op_k, xlab="# clusters", ylab="penalty")
```

So the optimal number of clusters according to the `kgs` function is the minimum value of `op_k`, as you can see in the plot. 
You can get it with

```
min(op_k)
```

Note that I set the maximum number of clusters allowed to 20. You can set this argument to `NULL`.

Check [this](https://www.r-bloggers.com/finding-optimal-number-of-clusters/) page for more methods.

Hope it helps you.

## Edit

To find which is the optimal number of clusters, you can do

```
op_k[which(op_k == min(op_k))]
```

#### Plus

Also see this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15376075/cluster-analysis-in-r-determine-the-optimal-number-of-clusters?rq=1) to find the perfect graphy answer from @Ben

## Edit

```
op_k[which(op_k == min(op_k))]
```

still gives penalty. To find the optimal number of clusters, use

```
as.integer(names(op_k[which(op_k == min(op_k))]))
```

Comment: Hi, thank you so much! I got now a plot, but I cant post it here I think? Dont know how. And min(op_k) is 7.628466. Does that mean 7 or 8 clusters? The plot looks like there are 5...the first 4 are high up, the 5th is very far on the buttom and then all others going up step by step.

Comment: @Essi the value of `min(op_k)` is just a penalty calculated by the `kgs`. The optimal number of cluster is that indicated by this value. I edited my answer so you can get the optimal number of clusters.

Answer (score 1):

I'm happy to learn about the kgs function. Another option is using the find_k function from the dendextend package (it uses the average silhouette width). But given the kgs function, I might just add it as another option to the package.
Also note the dendextend::color_branches function, to color your dendrogram with the number of clusters you end up choosing (you can see more about this here: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dendextend/vignettes/introduction.html#setting-a-dendrograms-branches )

Comment: Thank you very much! I will try it!