# R — Automatic Optimal Number of Clusters Sequence Algorithm

Tags: r, validation, cluster-analysis, sequence, hierarchical-clustering

I am interested in finding a `function` to **automatically** determine the optimal number of clusters in R.

I am using a sequence algorithm from the package `TraMineR` to compute my distances.

```
library(TraMineR) 

data(biofam)
biofam.seq <- seqdef(biofam[501:600, 10:25])

## OM distances ##
biofam.om <- seqdist(biofam.seq, method = "OM", indel = 3, sm = "TRATE", 
full.matrix = F)
```

For instance, `hclust` can simply be used like this

```
h = hclust(as.dist(biofam.om), method = 'ward')
```

and the number of clusters can then be **manually** determined with

```
clusters = cutree(h, k = 7)
```

**What I would like** ultimately is to automatically set up in the `cutree` function the `k` number of clusters, based on an "ideal" number of clusters.

It seems that the package `clValid` has such function (`optimalScores`). 
However, I cannot pass a distance matrix into `clValid`.

```
clValid(obj = as.dist(biofam.om), 2:6, clMethods = 'hierarchical')
```

I get this error

> argument 'obj' must be a matrix, data.frame, or ExpressionSet object

I get the same kind of error using other packages such as `NbClust`

```
NbClust(diss = as.dist(biofam.om), method = 'ward.D')
```

> Data matrix is needed.

Anyone knows how to solve this or knows other packages?

Thanks.

Comment: try `NbClust(diss = as.matrix(as.dist(biofam.om)), method = 'ward.D')`. In documentation it says a matrix is required

Comment: You can use the `kgs` penalty function to get the optimal number of clusters. You will need your `hclust` and distance matrix objects. Also see this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47776054/r-cluster-analysis-and-dendrogram-with-correlation-matrix/47777081#47777081).

Answer (score 1):

There are several different criteria for measuring the quality of a clustering result and choosing the optimal number of clusters. Take a look at the weightedCluster package: http://mephisto.unige.ch/weightedcluster/WeightedCluster.pdf
You can easily compare between different measures and numbers of clusters.