# Convert a distance matrix to a cluster table with R

Tags: r, matrix, distance

here Is a dendrogram, as you can see there are 3 clusters:

[image]

here is the corresponding distance table :

```
> round(cophenetic(hclust_avg), digits=3)

           g1    g2    g3    g4    g5    g6    g7    g8    g9   g10
    g2  0.000                                                      
    g3  3.027 3.027                                                
    g4  3.027 3.027 0.000                                          
    g5  0.000 0.000 3.027 3.027                                    
    g6  0.000 0.000 3.027 3.027 0.000                              
    g7  0.000 0.000 3.027 3.027 0.000 0.000                        
    g8  3.027 3.027 2.683 2.683 3.027 3.027 3.027                  
    g9  3.027 3.027 2.683 2.683 3.027 3.027 3.027 0.000            
    g10 0.000 0.000 3.027 3.027 0.000 0.000 0.000 3.027 3.027      
    g11 3.027 3.027 0.000 0.000 3.027 3.027 3.027 2.683 2.683 3.027
```

and what I would like is to get from this a table such as :

```
g1  g2  g3  g4  g5  g6  g7  g8  g9 g10 g11 
1   1   2   2   1   1   1   3   3   1   2
```

where I put in the same group the number values that have a distance = 0.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Hi chippycentra. Please show us what you have tried! :)

Comment: Hello @zabop , I tried `cut_avg <- cutree(hclust_avg, k = 3)`  but this solution is not really suitable because the K will change at any time I use the script and is difficult to estimate with the real data...

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47776054/r-cluster-analysis-and-dendrogram-with-correlation-matrix/47777081#47777081) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15376075/cluster-analysis-in-r-determine-the-optimal-number-of-clusters?rq=1) posts

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: Did your problem solved?

Comment: By using the best k value yes but not with the initial question.