# How to matching employee's title in databes to simplify names

Tags: python, r, machine-learning, text-mining, data-science

I'm preparing a database analysis from the website:

```
 https://www.kaggle.com/c/predicting-loan-default/data
```

My variable emp_length takes about 3000 different values. Some values are the same or have the same keyword (for example account, accountant, accounting, account specialist, acct.). Some words contain errors or are shortcuts. I want to decrease the values to simplify the names and encode as numeric values. I tried to find keywords with text mining in R, but I'm not convinced that this is the right way. Does anyone have any idea for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to adapt this "data science" approach:

Example input data:

```
emp_length<-c("account","accountant","accounting","account specialist","Data Scientist","Data Science Expert")
```

String distance + clustering

```
cluster<-kmeans(stringdistmatrix(emp_length,emp_length,method="jw"),centers=2)
cluster_n<-cluster$cluster
```

A possible grouping of the labels

```
cbind(emp_length,cluster_n)
     emp_length            cluster_n
[1,] "account"             "2"      
[2,] "accountant"          "2"      
[3,] "accounting"          "2"      
[4,] "account specialist"  "2"      
[5,] "Data Scientist"      "1"      
[6,] "Data Science Expert" "1"
```

This could help in the detection of the label to group and convert in numeric format.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much. I have one question, how to choose centers when I don' know how many levels I have?

Comment: You can apply one or more thecniques described in this topic https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15376075/cluster-analysis-in-r-determine-the-optimal-number-of-clusters over the stringdistmatrix to find the optimal number of clusters